# Precedence operator between * and / in PHP

Tags: operator-keyword, operator-precedence

```
$c = 8 / (12 - 8) * 4;

echo $c; //output 8
```

I read in http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php. I think that it should be 8/16 instead of 8. Are there anybody help me explaination, thanks.

Comment: 1. 12 - 8 = 4 |
2. 8 / 4 = 2 | 
3. 2 * 4 = 8 | 

I would say 8 is correct

Comment: How do you get to 8/12?

Comment: Why do you think it should be `8/12`?

Comment: i think you should retake a maths class

Comment: yes, i mean that  it is 8/16.

Answer (score 0):

$c = 8 / (12 - 8) * 4;

echo $c; //output 8

Because (12 - 8) equal 4 it will execute first. After this execution we will get

$c = 8 /  4 * 4;

After that the result will be 2 * 4 php will execute 8 / 4 and give a result 2.
Finally the result will be 8.

In this code Parentheses  will get first priority, then the division and finally multiplication.

Comment: Why is first the division and then the multiplication? It sounds like the division has higher precedence than multiplication and this is not true.

Comment: @axiac If they have equal precedence, their associativity decides how they are grouped.  Division is left-associative so they group `(8/4)*4`

Comment: @jgmh of course it is as you explained. My question was addressed to Alok Paul as, from their explanation, one could understand that after the subexpression in parentheses is computed, the next operation is always the division and only then the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

operators' precedence order from high to low：`/` == `*` > `-`

But `()` will enforce priority to the highest.

Operators with the same precedence, operations order will be from left to right.

so, the operations process is:
    
    `<?php
    $c = 8 / (12 - 8) * 4;
    // Give priority to parentheses inside
    $c = 8 / 4 * 4; // 12 - 8 ==> 4
    // operators with precedence, from left to right
    $c = 2 * 4; // 8 / 4 ==> 2
    $c = 8; // 2 * 4 ==> 8`

**This involves only the basic mathematical arithmetic**